# fetching the label text from database in C#

Tags: c#

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='1'", conn);
            conn.Open();
            label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString();
            conn.Close();

            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='2'", conn1);
            conn1.Open();
            label2.Text = cmd1.ExecuteReader().ToString();
            conn1.Close();

            SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAZI-PC\\PROJECTACC;Initial Catalog=programDB;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select label_sh from label_text where label_form='2' and label_form_labelID='3'", conn2);
            conn2.Open();
            label3.Text = cmd2.ExecuteReader().ToString();
            conn2.Close();
        }
```

I am developing a small project in C#... Using Visiual Studio 2010... I want to fetch the label texts from database in order to change the user interface language with a button...
I wrote this code but there is a problem in SQLDATAREADER

in label text parts it shows 
             System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

I cant fix, could you help me?

Comment: What happens if you have 100 labels? Open and Close Connection 100 times?

Comment: yes you are right it is not optimum solution... is there any way to make a few query with one connection?

Comment: Open 1 connection then read all

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

```
label3.Text = (string) cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
```

if you want to use ExecuteReader you have to store the reader first, then call Read on it and fetch it values with reader.GetString(0);